# Python 3 - Loading a python 2 pickle file in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, python-2.x

I have see multiple solutions for loading python 2 pickle files in python 3. However, when I set the encoding to either **'latin-1'**, **'latin1'** or **'bytes'**, I am facing the issue below.

```
with open ("test.pkl", 'rb') as file:
    model = pickle.load(file, encoding='bytes')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/copyreg.py", line 43, in _reconstructor
    obj = object.__new__(cls)
TypeError: object.__new__(pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.MonthBegin) is not safe, use pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.MonthBegin.__new__()
```

Any fixes?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm looking at the example here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Is `file` just a str or is it an `io` object?

Comment: It's an io object @astrochun